# How to make a dynamic url public in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Our app is currently running fine and processing stuff, however, we also provide our users with an iframe with a url like so; https://rssfeeder.app/embed/v1/7TVWRAN4EZV8L7F but as you'll notice it redirect to validate access through Shopify store url. We'd like to make https://rssfeeder.app/embed/v1/ -- anything ---  to be public to skip the authentication.

Here is our routes.rb file;

```
get 'embed/v1/:id', to: 'pages#embed', as: 'embed'
```

Our pages controller looks like this for embed;

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def embed
    @feeds = Feed.where("uniqid = ?", params[:id])[0]
    @entry = Item.where("feed_id = ?", @feeds.id)
  end
end
```

To make that url public do I modify our routes.rb file like so;

```
get 'embed/v1/:id', to: 'pages#embed', controller: 'embed'
```

Comment: I do not see a redirect anywhere in the code posted so it is difficult to understand the question. It seems likely that `ApplicationController` is what is requiring the authentication and you just need to skip it for the `PagesController` or specifically the `embed` action. Either that or you have a route that is hiding this route in your routes.rb file

Comment: care to direct me towards a function I'd be putting in `ApplicationController` to skip an `embed` action in `PagesController`. Devise is within the app and its connected to Shopify system as well, so its hard to figure out since for approval purposes Shopify asks everything be validated and authenticated. However, in this case, the generated url doesn't need to be validated, since we want it public. All other data, should be closed.

Comment: i was thinking something like `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:embed]` in `ApplicationController` maybe

Comment: If that is a thing then yes but put it in the `PagesController` (you don't need to change the routing unless there is some other conflict). I am unfamiliar with your codebase and I have never used Shopify so I can't be of much assistance there. That being said your `embed` code can be changed to `@feed = Feed.find_by_uniqid(params[:id]); @entries = @feed.items` as long as the association between `Feed` and `Item` is defined correctly.

Comment: @engineersmnky looks like I had AuthorizedApplication from Shopify within my PageController and ApplicationController. Primarily, ApplicationController didn't need to be completely validated, just certain areas. Moving that around fixed my issue. Thank you for helping though :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing Authorization check in the `ApplicationController` which checks authorization overall app, and moved it only to controllers that needed to be checked for authorization `ok` by Shopify.

Comment: Yep, I normally make an intermediary base controller for this, instead of putting the auth check to all controllers. `class ProtectedController < ApplicationController`.

Comment: makes complete sense :) we are very novice in rails, thank you for the suggestion.